# Why are vertices not displayed using Graph API?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using this following code and notice when i try to view the vertices
it does not display anything on the console but the edges display successfully.

```
val vertexArray = Array((1L, ("Alice", 28)),(2L, ("Bob", 27)),(3L, ("Charlie", 65)),(4L, ("David", 42)),(5L, ("Ed", 55)),(6L, ("Fran", 50)))

val edgeArray = Array(Edge(2L, 1L, 7),Edge(2L, 4L, 2),Edge(3L, 2L, 4),Edge(3L, 6L, 3),Edge(4L, 1L, 1),Edge(5L, 2L, 2),Edge(5L, 3L, 8),Edge(5L, 6L, 3))


val vertexRDD: RDD[Vertex(Long, (String, Int))] = sc.parallelize(vertexArray)
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Int]] = sc.parallelize(edgeArray)

val graph: Graph[(String, Int), Int] = Graph(vertexRDD, edgeRDD)

graph.vertices.collect().foreach(println)
graph.edges.collect().foreach(println)
```

These also indicate the num of Vertices as 0.

```
graph.numEdges
graph.numVertices
```

Actually i was expecting graph.numVertices to print as 6 but it is 0
and     graph.vertices.collect().foreach(println)
i was expecting it to print all the vertices but it doesn't print any.

Answer (score 0):

This works when I start Spark in SA mode:

```
/usr/bin/spark-shell
```

I am using CDH5...

Earlier I've been starting Spark like this:

```
/home/cloudera/Downloads/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.3/bin/spark-shell
```

This appears to be resolved.